# Is there a function that provides these values?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, recurrence-relations, special-functions, recursion

While solving a problem, I reached a recursive solution of the form:

$$
f(x, N) = 2f(x-1,N+1) - f(x-2,N).
$$

I stumbled upon an approach to obtain the individual terms without a long recursive operation. I did not prove this, but it looked somehow logical and supported by Monte Carlo simulations.

$$
f(x, N) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{\lceil x/2 \rceil-1}(-1)^{i} 2^{x-2i}\binom{x-i-1}{i} f(1, N+x-1-2i).
$$

For example, for $x=6$, we have

$$
f(6,N) = 32f(1,N+5)-32f(1,N+3)+6f(1,N+1).
$$

I do this because $f(1,N)$ has an easy solution while $f(x,N)$ does not.

Is there a polynomial function that generates such coefficients? I assume this kind of a recursive relation should be common in math so that there might be more literature in it.

Here is a list of the values for small $x$:

- $x=3 \rightarrow [4,-1]$
- $x=4 \rightarrow [8,-4]$
- $x=5 \rightarrow [16,-12,1]$
- $x=6 \rightarrow [32,-32,6]$
- $x=7 \rightarrow [64,-80,24,-1]$
- $x=8 \rightarrow [128,-192,80, -8]$
- $x=9 \rightarrow [256,-448,240,-40,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See OEIS [A113156](https://oeis.org/A133156) with generating function $ \dfrac 1{1 - 2tx + t^2}$
i.e. ["Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: Is it common knowledge that Chebyshev Polynomials appear in recursive relations or was it just somehow luck?

Comment: Two questions here : many classical polynomials may be obtained this way, Bernoulli, Stirling, Gegenbauer (generalizing Chebyshev), Legendre and so on ([classical orthogonal polynomials)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_orthogonal_polynomials) $$-$$ How did I get this? Well typing 4,-1,8,-4,16 and so on at [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) (works fine for triangles too). Excellent continuation,

Comment: This was fantastically helpful, not just for the question at hand but also for other problems I might have. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped @C.Koca! OEIS is a great resource as well as free software like [pari/gp](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) (fast number theory) and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_software_for_mathematics) (Mathematica remains the best for symbolic integration but pari is faster!).

Comment: This was not directly related but somehow even more useful advise :) Thanks a lot!